# How do I dynamically add and remove css for the whole JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using `JDK8 build 87` and would like to dynamically add and remove `css stylesheets` such that they can be used by my whole `JavaFX` application.

At the moment I'm setting the default `styleSheet` using this command:

```
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_MODENA);
```

and then when I want to add an additional css style sheet I do this:

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.getInstance.addUserAgentStylesheet(styleSheet);
```

This works but I have two problems. Firstly, it is using a **private** `API` and secondly there doesn't seem to be a way to remove it once I have finished with it (I'm using `OSGI` so it is common for modules to come and go).

There was talk about moving `StyleManager` to **public** `API` at the start of 2012 but I'm not sure anything has happened about that.

Does anyone know of a public method to add `styleSheets` such that they apply to the whole `JavaFX` application? Also how would one remove them?

**(I don't have the privileges to create the new javafx-8 tag)**

Comment: BTW, if you will not find an appropriate solution, you can try to look up for tweak or RFE on javafx-jira bugtracker, and if you will not find any one - file your tweak - while it is not late..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Global Stylesheet for your GUI application](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/03/global-stylesheet-for-your-javafx-application/):

```
// load default global stylesheet
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(null);
// add custom global stylesheet
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(AQUA_CSS_NAME);
```

However as Boomah points out, `StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet` is not part of the JavaFX API, so this method is really not recommended that it be used directly from user code.  Additionally, it only works for adding a global stylesheet and not for removing a such a stylesheet once the stylesheet has been added.

---

The more adventurous could create a patch to add Boomah's suggested feature by modifying the [StyleManager](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-common/src/com/sun/javafx/css/StyleManager.java) code to support removal of global stylesheets and modifying [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html) class source code to provide a public API for the new feature which makes use of the updated `StyleManager`, then submit the patch to [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) for inclusion in the JavaFX platform.

---

In the meantime you can manually set your user stylesheet on each of your application's scenes - kind of pain, but there you are . . .

Comment: I'm happy setting the top level style sheet to STYLESHEET_MODENA as shown in my example above. It is the StyleManager that is private api and even that doesn't have the ability to remove additional style sheets after they have been set.

Comment: Correct, to get the feature you want, you will need to submit a patch to implement the feature or [create a feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com)

Comment: OK, I spoke to Jonathan Giles about this. He suggested just adding onto all scenes as well. It's not a massive problem as I do have access to them all, it just seems there should be a better way to do this. Thanks

Comment: @Boomah StyleManager doesn't seem to have made it into public 9 api: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076423 - so even in future there is no clean way for globally adding styles (it'll get even worse, as the dirty access won't be possible)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the heads up. If that was the only missing thing I wouldn't be so bothered as there is a workaround. My current annoyance is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087922 There is no workaround and it makes any JavaFX application feel clunky. No one but me seems to care about it :(